# How to Reload a Vue table component after editing record?

Tags: vue.js, components

I am trying to reload the vue table component with new data after editing the record, but the table is getting updated only after a full page reload, I am using a sidebar window component to edit the table record, once the record is edited the table needs to be updated. Can anyone help to solve this issue with code.

My table component

```
  <template slot="thead">
    <vs-th sort-key="id">Id</vs-th>
    <vs-th sort-key="name">Name</vs-th>
    <vs-th sort-key="phone_number">Phone No</vs-th>
    <vs-th sort-key="location">Location</vs-th>
  </template>

  <template slot-scope="{data}">
      <tbody>
        <vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data">

           <vs-td>
            <p class="font-medium truncate">{{ tr.id }}</p>
          </vs-td>  

         <vs-td>
            <p class="font-medium truncate">{{ tr.first_name }}</p>
          </vs-td>  


          <vs-td>
          <p class="font-medium truncate">{{ tr.phone_number}}</p>
          </vs-td>

          <vs-td>
          <p class="font-medium truncate">{{ tr.location}}</p>
          </vs-td>

       </vs-tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
```

Method to edit record in modal component

```
  editData () {
  this.$validator.validateAll()
      let obj = {
        id: this.dataId,
        first_name: this.datafirst_name,
        phone_number: this.dataphone_number,
        location: this.datalocation,

      }
       this.$vs.loading();

        this.$store.dispatch("userManagement/updateLead", obj)

     .then(() => {
      //  location.reload();

       this.$vs.loading.close();

       alert('Updated');            
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.$vs.loading.close();
         alert('Update error');
      });
      this.$emit('closeSidebar')
      this.$validator.reset()
      this.resetFields();


},
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload all the page or table. First of all - it's better to use `id` as `key` with `v-for`, not `index`(it will identify editable row more clearly). Then you can just `emit` edit event and change item in table:

```js
this.$emit('edit', this.obj);
```

Then just listen to this event in table and edit item there:

```html
<modal-component @edit="editEvent"></modal-component>
```

```js
editEvent(obj) {
    this.data = this.data.map(item => {
        if(parseInt(item.id, 10) === parseInt(obj.id, 10)) {
            return obj;
        }

        return item;
    });
}
```

It will be faster then waiting API response(Also you should handle errors, but it's on you).
Otherwise, if you don't have access to modal component, you should store data in storage and get it from there (Update data in `action`).